# Sublime Text from Command Line on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, windows-8.1, sublimetext3, git-bash

I installed Sublime Text 3 and wanted to know how to open sublime files from gitbash or commandline in windows 8. I am into rails development.

Comment: the answer for that is not working on windows 8

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why the answer from the 'possible duplicate' is not working? What have you tried, where did you find a problem?

Answer (score 1):

open powershell 
Set-Alias subl 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe'